# SSH Reverse tunneling trough google cloud and accessing on shell in different network ( not google could)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh-tunnel

Hi I want to Access my raspberry pi through a ssh reverse tunnel on google cloud and than Access the reverse connection through a shell on my pc ( that is not in the same network raspberry).

Answer (score 0):

Yes was Possible. You have to add the ssh certificat (code,handshake) to the vm (googel cloud) in order to acces the it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).